# Creating image link creates a path adding controller name

Tags: image, cakephp, path, controller

I am trying to implement a image gallery in cakephp with below structure:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->image('gallery/fashion/fashion-photography-guwahati-'.$i.'.jpg',
            array('class'=>'img img-responsive')
        ),
        'gallery/fashion/fashion-photography-guwahati-big-'.$i.'.jpg',
            array(
              'class' => 'col-sm-4',
              'escape' => false,
              'data-toggle' => 'lightbox',
              'data-gallery' => 'multiimages',
            )
        );
```

But the above script outputs `HTML`:

```
<a href="/nitish/cakem/galleries/gallery/fashion/fashion-photography-guwahati-big-4.jpg" class="col-sm-4" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="multiimages">

<img src="/nitish/cakem/img/gallery/fashion/fashion-photography-guwahati-4.jpg" class="img img-responsive" alt="" />

</a>
```

As you can see in the `anchor` path, additional `galleries` directory is added. How to remove this ?

NB: `galleries` is my controller name

Comment: The user will sent to where when clicks on the image? Could you please describe what actually you are planning? Are you trying thumbnail or you will redirect to product details page?

Answer (score 1):

Strart you paths with a slash:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image('/gallery/fashion/fashion-photography-guwahati-'.$i.'.jpg',
        array('class'=>'img img-responsive')
    ),
    '/gallery/fashion/fashion-photography-guwahati-big-'.$i.'.jpg',
    array(
      'class' => 'col-sm-4',
      'escape' => false,
      'data-toggle' => 'lightbox',
      'data-gallery' => 'multiimages',
    )
);
```